# Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'

Tags: elassandra

$java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

$sudo bin/cassandra -eR
Starting cassandra with org.apache.cassandra.service.ElassandraDaemon
--folowing error comes--
$ [0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:bin/../logs/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate.
See [Cassandra start error with ThreadPriorityPolicy=42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844252/cassandra-start-error-with-threadprioritypolicy-42)

Edit **%CASSANDRA_HOME%/conf/jvm.options** file:

If you run Cassandra under root on Linux,
replace `-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42` with `-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1`
Otherwise remove `-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42` line altogether.