# Cassandra - Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

During single node installation when I am trying to see the `nodetool status`, this below error message is coming:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-128:~/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/bin$ ./cassandra -R
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-128:~/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/bin$ [0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:./../logs/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `ThreadPriorityPolicy` is not a valid JVM option in whichever version of Java you are using.  You can see this by checking the version from the command prompt:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.17.1) (Alpine 8.275.01-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Note that Cassandra 3.x will only function with Java 8.  You are likely seeing this error, because the Java 8 options specified in `cassandra-env.sh` are not valid with your version of Java.  Install the latest Java 8, or run Cassandra with Docker.

Edit:

Based on this: [Cassandra start error with ThreadPriorityPolicy=42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844252/cassandra-start-error-with-threadprioritypolicy-42)

Try setting `ThreadPriorityPolicy=1`.

Comment: I am using this java  version jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz  but still it comes errorImproperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: @Pritish Edit made.

Comment: @Pritish  Also, that parameter setting (42) should work with JDK 8.  I wonder if you have 9+ somewhere on your machine that Cassandra is managing to find?

Comment: The waring about `-Xloggc` being deprecated also suggests that it's not running on Java 8.